# adding a message at the end of a bag file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone
Is it possible to add a message at the end of a bag file (the messages is of the same kind of the ones already in the bag)?

thanks for support.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52001/adding-a-message-at-the-end-of-a-bag-file/) by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can modify bag files using the [rosbag code API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Code%20API) including appending messages.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2013-01-15**:
thanks. my further question is: when a bag, containing messages about more that one topic, is played, how are messages sent? are they sent simply in the order they were recorded or topic by topic?

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2013-01-15**:
will my added messages be sent as the last one, anyway, since i recorded it at the end?